# Performance of std::vector with 4 dimensions

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, vector

I am looking for the fastest way to save double values in a data structure which runs over 4 indexes.

I tried it with std::vector in the following way:

```
vector<vector<vector<vector<double>>>> myValues
```

My program has a lot of operations in which the values of mValues are read and changed and I would like to improve the performance.

How fast is this 4-dimensional vector structure? Are there better options which would be more appropriate?

Thank you very much.

Comment: How are you mapping double to four indices? What will be the contents of four indices if I want to store 3.14159?

Comment: cannot answer without relevant data. Are the dimensions of the array fixed? A vector of vector of vector of vector gives you a lot more flexibility than you probably want.

Comment: Did you try the usual, one `vector<double>`, where (i,j,k,l) corresponds to index `i*cst1+j*cst2+k*cst3+l`?

Comment: _"How fast is this 4-dimensional vector structure?"_ Why are you asking us? You're the one who has the structure. _How fast_ is not a question that means anything without measurements or some proposed alternative to create a relative benchmark against.

Comment: The dimension is fixed. I am trying to solve a programming task in which I need a data structure which runs over 4 indexes, but my program is much slower (10 times slower) as the results which are given by another implementation (I do not have the implementation, just the computational results). Therefore I considered that this 4-dimensional vector structure could cause these runtime issues.

Answer (score 7):

Internally, a vector stores its data in a dynamically allocated array, so a 4 level vector will have same performances an array of pointers to arrays of pointers to arrays of pointers to arrays of double values.

The alternative would be to allocate a 4D linear array (possibly through a vector) and manually do the index computations (index of `arr[i][j][k][l]` is `l + level4_size * (k + level3_size * (j + level2_size * i))`, if will be certainly more efficient in memory usage, unsure for speed because it could depends of the actual accesses. If you really care for speed, you should benchmark both implementations in your actual environment.

Comment: I am trying to solve a programming task in which I need a data structure which runs over 4 indexes, but my program is much slower (10 times slower) as the results which are given by another implementation (I do not have the implementation, just the computational results). Therefore I considered that this 4-dimensional vector structure could cause these runtime issues. I do not care about a few seconds, but I am worried because my implementation is that slow. Did I understand you correctly? My implementation is not wrong, but maybe the alternative could perform better?

Comment: @do-math: a great performance difference (10 times) is generally not caused by a low level  optimisation (arrays of pointers against nD-arrays) but by algorithmics differences. I would expect at most a 2 ratio (and in special use cases) for the former.

Comment: Agreed. Likely you need to change your algorithm not the data structure.